# Regex with any character and maybe a space not working

Tags: regex, linux, wordpress, sed

I am using sed for this, but it is about the same thing with other regex.

Trying to get the DB_NAME, which in this case would be **test**, from a WordPress wp-config.php file. Also, I can't control if single ('), or double (") quotes are being used. Spaces may exist... So these are some examples of what I can expect:

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'test' );
define('DB_NAME','test');
define( "DB_NAME", "test" );
```

Here is what I'm using:

```
sed -E -n "s/define\([[:space:]]?.DB_NAME.,[[:space:]]?.(.*).[[:space:]]?\);/\1/p" wp-config.php
```

This is the output:

```
test'
test
test"
```

With the **?** after the last **[[:space:]]**, only the second line returns the expected **test**. The others have the quote appended.

Why is that? Shouldn't the **.** catch the quotes and **[[:space:]]?** catch a space, if it's there?

I know I can use:

```
['\|\"]
```

to capture either quotes instead of the dot, but wondering why this is...

Comment: Try the _--regexp-extended_ switch.

Comment: If the lines in your real input files don't always contain `define` and `DB_NAME` then update the example in your question to make it more realistic. If they do then you don't need to test for `define` and `DB_NAME` in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(.*)` captures the quote, and the `.` outside of the parens captures the trailing white space, and then `[[:space:]]?` matches 0 characters. Try something like this:

```bash
 sed -E -n "s/define\([[:space:]]?.DB_NAME.,[[:space:]]?['\"](.*)['\"][[:space:]]?\);/\1/p"
input.txt
test
test
test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F "['\"]*" '{print $4}' file.php
test
test
test
```

Comment: I suspect the OP really needs to test for `define` and `DB_NAME` too and their sample input/output just isn't adequate to demonstrate their real problem.

Comment: Possibly, but they can build a solution on top of this if needed